# Orchard CMS on Load Balanced web servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, load-balancing, orchardcms

I'm considering running Orchard CMS on load balanced servers. 
(Two web servers with hardware load balancers, and a SAN file share)

I've been unable to find any info on this.

I'm wondering if there will be update and cacheing issues - if pages are cached, will updates be propagated to the other server?

I'm also wondering if there are likely to be any install pitfalls?

Does anyone have any info or experience on this?

Many thanks....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to define a machine key: http://orchardproject.net/docs/Setting-up-a-machine-key.ashx
Other than that, if all the servers are working off the same share, you should be all set.
There is no caching out of the box, but any modules that do caching will just cache everything on each server as needed. What will not work is triggered cache invalidation (http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/17361).

Comment: Brill - thanks very much for the comprehensive answer Bertrand. And great stuff on Orchard, I think I read someone describe the 'clean code' as very appealing. +1 for that.